# How can I add and remove specific data in local storage?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, local-storage

I started learning Angular recently, I'm trying to make a github search app with the github api but I have some problems with local storage. I have an add to favorite button for pin the profile to the page. When it's pinned remove favorite button should be appear instead of add to favorite button and it should be remove the profile. I thought I could do this with adding and removing profiles from local storage. I have an user variable which holds the profile info as an object when the user types username in the search bar. Then I'm passing this data to local storage and take all the local storage data to make it an array so I can display it with *ngFor. The problem is when I pin the profile, I can't remove permanently specific profile from the page. I can only delete pinned profiles temporarily. I'm dealing with this problem for two days, I have shared the part what I did until now. The purple area is where the pinned profiles are shown.

[image: The purple area is where pinned profiles are shown.]

**home.component.html:**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="profile" (ngModelChange)="detectChange($event)" (keyup)="findProfile()" placeholder="Enter the username..." class="input">
<div style="background-color: lightslategrey;">
  <ng-template [ngIf]="profile !== '' && user">
    <img [src]="user.avatar_url" alt="" class="userAvatar">
    <p>Username: {{user.login}}</p>
    <p>Location: {{user.location}}</p>
    <p>E-mail: {{user.email}}</p>
    <p>Blog Link: {{user.blog}}</p>
    <p>Member Since: {{user.created_at}}</p>
    <button [routerLink]="['', user.login.toLowerCase(), user.id ]" class="viewProfileButton" a>View
      Profile</button><br>
    <button (click)="localStorage()"  class="viewProfileButton">Add to Favorite</button>
  </ng-template>
</div>

<div style="background-color: rgb(106, 106, 170);" *ngFor="let item of display">
  <button (click)="consoleLog()">consoleLog</button>
  <p>Username: {{item.login}}</p>
  <p>Location: {{item.location}}</p>
  <p>ID: {{item.id}}</p>
  <button (click)="localStorage(item.id)">Add to favoriteeee</button>
  <button (click)="removeLocal(item.id)" class="viewProfileButton">Remove Favorite</button>
</div>
<button (click)="consoleLog()" class="viewProfileButton">Console Log</button>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**home.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from '../http.service';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
import { JsonPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { bindCallback } from 'rxjs';
import { FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  user: any;
  profile: any;
  display: any;
  local: any;
  randomNumber: any;
  randomString: any;
  idString: any;
  keys: any;
  closeDiv: boolean = true;
  constructor(private userData: HttpService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.display = Object.values(localStorage).map((val: any) => JSON.parse(val));
    console.log('ngOnInit Works', this.display);
  }

  findProfile() {
    this.userData.updateProfile(this.profile);
    this.userData.getUser().subscribe((result) => {
      this.user = result;
    });
  }

  localStorage(id: any) {
    this.idString = JSON.stringify(id);
    localStorage.setItem(this.idString, JSON.stringify(this.user));
    this.display = Object.values(localStorage).map((val: any) => JSON.parse(val));
    console.log(Object.values(this.display));
  }

  removeLocal(id: any) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.display.length; ++i) {
      if (this.display[i].id === id) {
        this.display.splice(i, 1);
        localStorage.removeItem(this.display[i].id);
      }
    }
  }

  detectChange(ev: any) {
    ev.length > 0 ? (this.closeDiv = false) : (this.closeDiv = true);
  }

}
```

Comment: It is hard to understand your problem. Have a look here for your future questions; https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

in component.ts

```
let item = 1;
`
localStorage.setItem('itemName',Item);
const getItem = localStorage.getItem('itemName')
```

so constant getItem will have your value. you can do the same with an array

Comment: Yes I know, but in this case it doesn't work. Because I'm taking the data from local storage and make it an array, I don't have an array at first. But if you know a way to practice, I would be glad if you explain.

Comment: first make an empty array=[]; then, store your data to the array. then keep array in localstorage like mentioned above.